# Renaming the oldest file in pairs of files with the same prefix

Tags: linux, bash

I have pairs of files with the same prefix in a directory with other files which don't exist in pairs. All files start with four digits. I need to find the oldest file of each pair and rename it. e.g. from:

```
0772_old_file.md
0772_new_file.md
```

to:

```
0772_old_file.md_old
0772_new_file.md
```

For a single pair of files I got as far as:

```
find . -name '0772*'| ls -rt | head -1
```

This outputs:

```
./0772_old_file.md
```

I anticipate that putting a further pipe to xargs is a way to rename this file but can't figure out the syntax.

Help with renaming a single pair is a step forwards. A bash script or one-liner that finds and renames the oldest file of every pair of files in the whole directory is even better.

Comment: The **older** of the two is `0772_new_file.md`? Well, no wonder you want to rename it.

Comment: My mistake, I've corrected the question. Thanks for picking this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `find` to print the last modification times (seconds since epoch) and names (separated by a space), `sort` to sort by last modification times from newest to oldest, `awk` to select only the pairs and print only the oldest in each pair, and a `while` loop to rename:

```
find . -type f -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*' -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -nr |
  awk '{sub(/^[^ ]* /,""); p = substr($0,1,4); num[p]++; name[p] = $0}
       END {for(p in num) if(num[p] == 2) print name[p]}' |
  while IFS= read -r file; do mv "$file" "${file}_old"; done
```

`find` selects all files (`-type f`) which name starts with 4 digits and a underscore (`-name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*'`), and prints their last modification time (seconds since epoch), a space, the file path and a newline (`-printf '%T@ %p\n'`).

`sort` sorts numerically (`-n`) and in reverse order (`-r`). Newer files will thus come first.

In the `awk` script we remove the leading timestamp and the following space (`sub(/^[^ ]* /,"")`), store the 4 first characters prefix of the file name in variable `p` (`p = substr($0,1,4)`), count the number of files with this prefix in array `num` (`num[p]++`), store the last encountered file name with this prefix in array `name` (`name[p] = $0`). At the `END` we loop over all keys of array `num` and, if the count is 2, print the corresponding entry in array `name`, which is the last (second) encountered name with this prefix, that is, the oldest of the two.

`IFS=` preserves the leading (but in this case there cannot be leading spaces, as `find` selects files with 4 leading digits) and trailing spaces.

Note: this works if your file names do not contain newline characters (but they can contain tabs or spaces). If they do, things are a bit more complex, we must use the NUL character (ASCII code 0) as record separator, because it is the only character that cannot be found in a file path. With GNU `awk` (some other `awk` do not support the NUL record separator):

```
find . -type f -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*' -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -znr |
  awk -v RS='\0' '
    {sub(/^[^ ]* /,""); p = substr($0,1,4); num[p]++; name[p] = $0}
    END {for(p in num) if(num[p] == 2) printf("%s\0", name[p])}' |
  while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do mv "$file" "${file}_old"; done
```

In `sort` (`-z`), GNU `awk` (`-v RS='\0'`) and `read` (`-d ''`) we indicate that the records are NUL-separated. In `find` and `awk` we print a NUL instead of a newline at the end of each record.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp.

Firstly, I created a directory of randomly generated files with names according to that pattern: four digits, underscore, (`"new"` | `"old"`), `"_file.md"`:

```
$ ls -C | head -4
0000_new_file.md  2476_old_file.md  5001_new_file.md  7479_new_file.md
0001_new_file.md  2483_new_file.md  5004_old_file.md  7480_old_file.md
0003_new_file.md  2487_old_file.md  5015_old_file.md  7481_new_file.md
0008_old_file.md  2503_old_file.md  5018_new_file.md  7481_old_file.md
```

Some of them have formed `old`/`new` pairs by chance. Some are singletons. Above we can see that `7481` is a pair.

At the REPL (read-eval print loop):

```
This is the TXR Lisp interactive listener of TXR 291.
Quit with :quit or Ctrl-D on an empty line. Ctrl-X ? for cheatsheet.
1> (flow "*.md"
     glob
     (group-by (do if-match `@{prefix #/\d+/}@suffix` @1 prefix))
     (each-match ((@f1 @f2) (hash-values @1))
       (when (path-older f2 f1)
         (swap f2 f1))
       (put-line `@f1 is older than @f2`)
       (put-line `rename to @{f1}_old`)))
1430_old_file.md is older than 1430_new_file.md
rename to 1430_old_file.md_old
2246_old_file.md is older than 2246_new_file.md
rename to 2246_old_file.md_old
0094_old_file.md is older than 0094_new_file.md
rename to 0094_old_file.md_old
1367_old_file.md is older than 1367_new_file.md
rename to 1367_old_file.md_old
6777_new_file.md is older than 6777_old_file.md
rename to 6777_new_file.md_old
7023_new_file.md is older than 7023_old_file.md
rename to 7023_new_file.md_old
1748_old_file.md is older than 1748_new_file.md
rename to 1748_old_file.md_old
5396_new_file.md is older than 5396_old_file.md
rename to 5396_new_file.md_old
[... hundreds more ...]
```

That's a dry run that only prints information about the pairs.

To do the rename we can call `` (rename-path f1 `@{f1}_old`) ``.

Answer (score 1):

With your given/sample file names, using `find` the `bash` shell, a `while` loop and the builtin read `read` and `mv` to rename the files, something like:

```
while IFS= read -r files; do
  if [[ ! -e "${files}_old" && -e "${files/old/new}" ]]; then
    echo mv -v "$files" "${files}_old"
  fi
done < <(find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_old*.md' -type f)
```

---

An alternative using the POSIX `sh` shell:

```
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_old*.md' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    if [ ! -e "${f}_old" ]; then
      a=${f%%_*}; b=${f##*_}
      [ -e "${a}_new_$b" ] && {
        echo mv -v "$f" "${f}_old"
      }
    fi
  done' sh {} +
```

---

- See [Understand-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)
- See the [POSIX Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)
- See the [Bash Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
- See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- See `help test`
- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output and to actually rename the files.

---

Using `find` is not needed if recursion is not required, e.g. there are no sub directories that contain the files in question, a for loop should suffice, using `bash` with `array`, something like:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
files=([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_old*.md)
(( ${#files[*]} )) || {
  printf >&2 'directory does not contain files ending in *.md!\n'
  exit 1
}
shopt -u nullglob dotglob

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  if [[ ! -e "${file}_old" && -e "${file/old/new}" ]]; then
    echo mv -v "$file" "${file}_old"
  fi
done
```

---

- See  [How can I check whether a directory is empty or not?  How do I check for any *.mpg files, or count how many there are?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash (except for the `mv`) code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

prev_file='' prev_prefix=''
for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*.md; do
    prefix=${file%%_*}
    if [[ $prefix == "$prev_prefix" ]]; then
        [[ $file -ot $prev_file ]] && oldfile=$file || oldfile=$prev_file
        echo mv -v -- "$oldfile" "${oldfile}_old"
    fi

    prev_file=$file prev_prefix=$prefix
done
```

- It assumes that pairs are distinguished by having the same 5-character (4 digits followed by underscore) prefix.
- It makes no other assumptions about filenames.  In particular, it does not assume that names contain the strings `old` or `new`.
- It works for filenames containing unusual characters, including newlines.
- It depends on the fact that lists of paths generated by globs (particularly `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*.md`) are sorted by name, ensuring that pairs appear consecutively in the list.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${file%%_*}`.  (It expands to the value of `$file` with the first underscore and everything after it removed.)
- If both files have exactly the same timestamp then the one that appears first on the list sorted by name will be renamed.  The code will need to be changed if that is not what you want.
- The code makes no attempt to handle the case where three or more files have the same prefix.  It may do unexpected things if that occurs.
- Remove the `echo` to make the code actually rename files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short version to accomplish what you set out to do that I hope is more readable.

```
#!/bin/sh

prefixes=`ls *_* | cut -d"_" -f1 | sort | uniq -c | grep -v -w 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
    
for prefix in $prefixes ; do
        echo $prefix
        ls -tr "${prefix}_"* | head -1 | xargs -t -i mv {} {}.md
done
```

- The first line is getting the unique list of prefixed file names
  that don't belong to single files
- The `uniq -c | grep -w -v 1`
  is counting prefix matches and excluding single matches with the -w option
  to avoid matching inside the filename.
- On the `for` loop it's looking for oldest of the matching
  prefixed files and renaming the first one.